# Roles and Permission on dashboard enterprise edition

Tags: roles, pentaho

Development Tool: Pentaho 4.5 enterprise edition

I have one issue regarding roles and permission.

I have one dashboard(enterprise one), i have added three prompts say p1, p2 and p3. Data in p1 and p3 is coming directly from DB (i.e. they are not dependent on any other parameter) whereas p2 have dependency in p1. In short we are trying to achieve cascading thing in our prompt section.

1. firstly i signed in as joe having roles(Admin, Authenticated and ceo). I can do cascading easily.
2. Then i signed in as suzy (Authenticated and cto). I can see data in p1 and p3. However I am not able to see anything on p2.

As i am able to do cascading thing as joe (in short any user with Role Admin) not as suzy..

So suggest me any possible solution.. coz as per our requirement there will be some user those will have only Authenticated / cto role.. so the cascading should work for all user, not just for user with role Admin.

Answer (score 0):

Try verifying the share option or permission of each content in p2. Are you able to find and see the original report (content) in p2? You can find it when you login as joe.

Comment: Thanks for information.. 

But how can we access share option/permission of each content?

Comment: I have given execute and create permission to my dashboard.. share option is visible for user joe and it's not visible for suzy.. same set of permission is responsible for cascading for user joe but not for suzy.